# Core Data not saving in distribution build

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, testflight

I have a very strange problem where Core Data works fine in development (debug) builds, but in distribution (release) builds distributed over TestFlight, my NSManagedObjectContext objects are not saving correctly.

I'm observing two issues:

- NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification doesn't get sent when a context is saved.
- Data doesn't persist between launches.

What could be causing this ONLY in distribution builds? As far as I know, provisioning profiles don't affect Core Data.

Here's two relevant functions of my Core Data stack:

```
- (void)initializeCoreData
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    if ([self managedObjectContext]) return;

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"XXX" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    NSAssert(mom, @"%@:%@ No model to generate a store from", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
    NSAssert(coordinator, @"Failed to initialize coordinator");

    self.privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

    self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.managedObjectContext.parentContext = self.privateContext;



    // Persistence store
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    options[NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption] = @YES;
    options[NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption] = @YES;
//  options[NSSQLitePragmasOption] = @{ @"journal_mode":@"DELETE" };

    NSURL *documentsURL = [[NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    // TODO: use real store url
    NSURL *storeURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data2.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSAssert([coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error], @"Error initializing PSC: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);


}

- (void)save;
{
    if (![[self privateContext] hasChanges] && ![[self managedObjectContext] hasChanges]) return;

    [[self managedObjectContext] performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;

        NSAssert([[self managedObjectContext] save:&error], @"Failed to save main context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);

        [[self privateContext] performBlock:^{
            NSError *privateError = nil;
            NSAssert([[self privateContext] save:&privateError], @"Error saving private context: %@\n%@", [privateError localizedDescription], [privateError userInfo]);
        }];
    }];
}
```

Any thoughts?

Update: I tried launching a debug build and storing something in the Core Data database and it persists fine between launches, then deployed a release build without deleting the app to keep the data and the database seems empty, then deployed a debug build again and the existing database loads fine. So it seems that the release build has an issue with accessing the database file for some reason. Any thoughts why that would happen?

Comment: Those symptoms suggest that either (a) the save attempt is not actually happening, or (b) the save is failing but you're not logging the error. Check the save process and add details to your question.

Comment: I added some logs and I can confirm that the save is not failing. As far as the code path is concerned, the save goes through. It's just not persisting.

Comment: If it's not persisting then either (a) it wasn't attempted, (b) it failed, (c) you're saving to a different file somehow, or (d) you're removing the file at some point.

Comment: I edited the question with an update: I did a test to see if a release build can accessing a pre-persisted database, and it can't. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSAssert` does not normally run in a Release Build as `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is defined as part of the standard Xcode template. Or from the docs

> IMPORTANT Do not call functions with side effects in the condition
>   parameter of this macro. The condition parameter is not evaluated when
>   assertions are disabled, so if you call functions with side effects,
>   those functions may never get called when you build the project in a
>   non-debug configuration.

Basically don't do stuff you care about in an Assert. Its a debugging test. You really want be a bit more gentle here and soft fail.

```
if([[self managedObjectContext] save:&error] == NO){ 
    NSLog(@"Failed to save main context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
else {
    [[self privateContext] performBlock:^{
        NSError *privateError = nil;
        if([[self privateContext] save:&privateError] == NO){ 
            NSLog(@"Error saving private context: %@\n%@", [privateError localizedDescription], [privateError userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```